How can I prove (and visualize) that $\log \left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)$ equals $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{k+1} - x^k}{\log x}\ dx$?
Let $$F(k) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{k+1} - x^k}{\log x}\ dx$$ for $k > -1$.
It's can be shown that $$F(k) = \log  \left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)$$ (partial proof below).
Question
How can we understand or justify this intuitively, visually, or geometrically? I've tried exploring this from different angles, plotting different components of $F$, trying to understand their rate of change or limits or approximations, but nothing seems to make this make sense.
It's as if a machine spit out the proof, but I see no underlying concept or picture.  How can we visualize, or at least intuitively justify, the identity above?

Proof
$$
%\begin{align*}
%F(k) &= F(0) + \int_0^k \left[\frac{d}{dk} \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^{k+1} - x^k}{\log x}\ dx \right) \right]dk &\quad \small \text{ (by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)} \\
%&= F(0) + \int_0^k \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dk} \left (\frac{x^{k+1} - x^k}{\log x} \right) \ dx \ dk &\quad \small \text{ (by Leibniz Integration Rule)} \\
%&= 0 + \int_0^k \int_0^1 (x^{k+1} - x^k) \ dx \ dk \\
%&= \int_0^k \left( \frac{1}{k+2} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) \ dk \\
%&= \frac{\log (k+2)}{\log(k+1)}.
%\end{align*}
$$ Write $$G(x,k) := \frac{x^{k+1}-x^k}{\log x}.$$  Then
$$
\begin{align*}
F(k) &= F(0) + \int_0^k \left[\frac{d}{dk} \left(\int_0^1 G(x,k) \ dx \right) \right]dk &\quad \small \text{(by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)} \\
&= F(0) + \int_0^k \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dk} G(x,k) \ dx \ dk &\quad \small \text{ (by Leibniz Integration Rule)} \\
&= 0 + \int_0^k \int_0^1 (x^{k+1} - x^k) \ dx \ dk &\quad \small \text{ (* see note)}\\
&= \int_0^k \left( \frac{1}{k+2} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) \ dk \\
&= \log  \frac{k+2}{k+1}  &\quad \small \text{ (** see note)}.
\end{align*}
$$
(*): Important Note: When working this, I wrote down $G(0) = 0$ for this step, but see that my proof requires $F$, not $G$.  And $G(0)$ isn't even well formed.  Yet, Wolfram Alpha confirms the conclusion.
So I am indeed in need of some help here.
(**): Corrected, thank you to DMcMor.

I don't think your conclusion is correct. $F(0)$ is clearly well defined in the original integral, but in the provided answer $F(0)$ is a singularity.

The final answer should be $\log\left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)$ instead of $\frac{\log (k+2)}{\log(k+1)}$.

Not sure if this helps, but I think visualizing $G(k) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^k - 1}{\log x} \mathrm{d}x$ might be easier, which relates to $F(k) = G(k+1) - G(k)$. $G(k) = \int_0^1 \int_0^k x^y \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x$, and maybe we can get something from the plot of $z = x^y$.

Relevant.

changing variables $x=e^u$ (which is the natural thing to do to get rid of the $1/log$) gives you the integral $F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{(k+1)u}g(u)du$ where $g(u)=\frac{e^u-1}{u}$ is a nice function on $(-\infty,0)$ (positive and not quite integrable but "almost") so $F$ is as nice as you want on $(-1, \infty)$ as a function of $k$ due to the exponential decay at minus infinity of the integrand, and then the computation of $F$ is straightforward since $\frac{dF}{dk}=\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty}F(k)=0$

I’m now trying to explain it by the area bounded by a function $y=F’(a)$,
$a=k$, $a=k+1$ and the real axis as below:

where
$$
F(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^a-x^k}{\ln x} d x \textrm{ and } a\ge k
$$
Differentiating $F(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
F^{\prime}(a) =\int_0^1 x^a d x =\left[\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{a+1}
$$
Integrating back from $a=k$ to $a=k+1$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(k+1)&=F(k+1)-F(k)\\ & =\int_k^{k+1} F^{\prime}(a) d a \\
& =\int _k^{k+1}\frac{1}{a+1} da\\
& =[\ln (a+1)]_k^{k+1} \\
& =\ln \left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

One trick is to go to infinity. We show
$$(*)\quad  \lim_{b\to\infty} F(b)= 0.$$
Let $\epsilon\in (0,1)$. Then
\begin{align*}  F(b) &= \int_0^{1-\epsilon} x^{b-1} x\frac{x-1}{\log x}+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^b \frac{1-x}{\log x} dx\\
&\le (1-\epsilon)^{b-1} F(1) + \epsilon \int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{1-x}{\log x} dx\\
& \le (1-\epsilon)^{b-1} F(1)+ 2\epsilon,
\end{align*}
where the last inequality was due to the fact that $\frac{x-1}{\log x} \to 1$ as $x\to 1$ (reciprocal of derivative of $\log$ at $x=1$).
Therefore $\limsup_{b\to\infty} F(b) \le 2\epsilon$, which in turn implies $(*)$.
Next, as $\frac{d}{dk} x^k = x^k \log x$,
$$\frac{d}{dk} F(k) = \int_0^1 (x^{k+1}-x^{k}) dx = \frac{1}{k+2}- \frac{1}{k+1}.$$
Now let's integrate  this back
$$F(b) - F(a) = \ln (b+2) - \ln (a+2) - (\ln (b+1) - \ln (a+1))= \ln \frac{b+2}{b+1} - \ln \frac{a+2}{a+1},$$
and so taking $b\to\infty$ and using $(*)$ as well as $\lim_{b\to\infty} \ln \frac{b+2}{b+1}=0$ we have
$$ F(a) = \ln \frac{a+2}{a+1}.$$
